# Debian file transfer to USB flash drive weird behaviour

Tags: debian, usb-drive

When I attempt to transfer/copy a relatively large file onto a USB drive I get some unusual behaviour.

The transfer rate seems to be stable at first until the end of the transfer approaches. For example, transferring a 2 GB file, once 1.7 GB has been transferred the transfer rate seems to plummet from ~90 Mb/s to 10 Mb/s and stabilise at 10 for the remainder of the transfer.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or is anyone else experiencing this issue? Thanks.

Edit: I've actually noticed it's significantly worse than I had thought. It's starting at ~400 Mb/s and dropping exponentially until it reaches ~1 Mb/s.

Comment: We have edit history, so inserting the word "edit" is superfluous and highlights that you did want to spent time to  rewrite your post to add missing information in an integrated fashiion. You should do so and at the same time remove the thanks (which is irrelevant chit-chat. And you should think about providing a real question. The only **valid** answer we can give you now are Yes/Yes, Yes/No, No/Yes or No/No. Any other answers don't answer your questions. Please think about how that is going to help you.

Comment: The "edit:" is just force of habbit. There wasn't missing information at the time, if you read the edit it's rather obvious that I had a realisation after i had posted. I did post a "real" question, I wanted to know if there were others with the same problem and if they knew what the cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to (write) cache on the usb drive which can accept a specified amount of data to be buffered and be written to disk from the buffer. Using this technique you should be able to write 'normal/regular sized' files in a pretty fast way. If you write files which are bigger than the buffer, the buffer gets overloaded and the writes needs to go directly to the disk. In such case you will see a performance drop.